# Parallax - Getting text to scroll at 1/10th speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to get the text to scroll at the same speed as its parent div (which is scrolling at 1/10 speed). Currently, it is scrolling at normal speed. What am I doing incorrectly?

HTML:

```
<div id="blank" class="page">
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { background:url(images/background.gif); }
.page {  overflow: auto; width: 580px; color: white; }
#blank { background: url(images/02.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; height: 2300px;}
```

JS:

```
$('#blank').parallax("50%", 0, 0.1, true);
$('#blank p').parallax("50%", 0, 0.1, true);
```

Comment: I haven't used the parallax library before but I can see from inspecting the DOM in your demo that it is only affecting the `background-position` attribute of the <div> and <p> elements. You might need to hack the parallax library to make it work the way you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i have also never used the plugin. its pretty simple to do it without a plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var topDist = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#blank').css('margin-top', (topDist/10)*9);      
    });
});​
```

using the scroll top will give you the distance scrolled and then you can add that to margins, top positions, left positions, bg positions etc. hope this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/PHHrF/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BRMcm/1/    -here i just made the divs position absolute and shifted the margins.

Comment: this way will shift the whole div and not just the bg-image. i feel it works best with the position:fixed.

Comment: As I play with the values in topDist, one small change breaks it. Id there a rule-of-thumb to follow when using that variable/options?

Comment: the "var topDist = $(document).scrollTop();" will return the number of pixels scrolled when "topDist" is called. multiplying and dividing topDist will give you percentages of the scrolled distance. example, topDist/10 will give you a value 10% of the distance scrolled.